# Twilio Voice Access Token Expiration Time

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I am setting a programmable voice chat token using the following codes:

```
    const accessToken = new AccessToken(config.accountSid, config.apiKey, config.apiSecret);
    accessToken.identity = user_uid;

      var grant = new VoiceGrant({
        outgoingApplicationSid: config.twimlAppSid,
        incomingAllow: false,
      });

    accessToken.addGrant(grant);

    return resolve(JSON.stringify({ token: accessToken.toJwt() }));
```

With the previous deprecated method: `ClientCapability`, I was able to assign an expiration time for the generated capability with ttl property:

```
    const capability = new ClientCapability({
      accountSid: config.accountSid,
      authToken: config.authToken,
      ttl: 300
    });
```

With the new `AccessToken` and `VoiceGrant`, is it still possible to set an expiration time manually? I did not find any relevant section in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that we can passin an optional ttl setting when creating an access token:

```
const accessToken = new AccessToken(config.accountSid, config.apiKey, config.apiSecret, {ttl: 7200});
```

or

```
    accessToken.ttl = 7200;
```

It is specified in the [Twilio source code](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-node/blob/main/lib/jwt/AccessToken.js#L222).